# How to make a popover clickable inside window without closing it but close with outside click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How can I make my popover window clickable inside the window area  without closing but closes automatically whem outside the are is clicked?

Here is my current code that is trigured with a button click:

```
if (response.Success) {
  return showErrorPopup(errorButton, 'Error!', response.Entity.Exception);
} else {
  return showErrorPopup(errorButton, 'No Error', response.Message);
}
```

And the function that opens the popover window:

```
showErrorPopup = function(popupElem, title, content) {
  return popupElem.popover({
      animation: false,
      title: title,
      content: content,
      placement: 'left',
      trigger: 'focus',
      html: true
  }).popover('show');
};
```

Iv tried trigger: 'click' and that allows the popover window to remain open but doesn't close it automatically when clicked outside of the window.

Answer (score 0):

To determine a click outside, have you tried to use

```
$('.popupclass').blur(function () {
   $(this).hide();
}
```

Blur event is when user removes the focus (a mouse click or a tab focus can be the main reason for the focus) from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery popups usually add a div with 100% window's width and height between the popup and the page. So when user click outside the popup - actually click the div - it closes the popup. I believe this logic could be applied here.